# SQL/PHP query error

Tags: sql, mysql

I have the following error:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select manufacturers_id, manufacturers_name, manufacturers_image, date_added, la' at line 1

The query:

```
SELECT COUNT(
  SELECT manufacturers_id, 
         manufacturers_name, 
         manufacturers_image, 
         date_added, 
         last_modified 
    FROM manufacturers 
      ORDER BY manufacturers_name
) AS total
```

This happens also to some other categories in my website. All finish their line incomplete.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This query would do what you want:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total
FROM manufacturers
```

What's wrong with your query:

1. `COUNT()` accepts an expression or single column as parameter - you're passing multiple
2. `ORDER BY` doesn't make much sense as soon as what you need is just number of rows (for obvious reason that number doesn't depend on order)

Comment: where to write this using phpmyadmin

Comment: @Karl TinKode: In the same place you use your syntactically incorrect query

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because the code is not on here full but what I can see is the mysql/mysqli_query is missing, and the ";" at the end of the code.